# Silverlight Project -Expression Blend

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, expression-blend

Is there a way to apply bitmapeffects within a silverlight web project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight2 currently doesn't support any form of bitmap effects. The workaround to add bitmap effects to any elements in your Silverlight app, for example, a drop shadow, you would have to manually create the shadow of the UI element, and export it as an image, and place it within your silverlight application as an image.

If you're using Expression Design, all you need to do is copy and paste it to Expression Blend (make sure that your clipboard is set to Silverlight XAML), and it will automatically convert the bitmapeffect to a seperate image.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to in silverlight 3.  Don't think it's possible in earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible in Silverlight 3, the beta of which shipped a few months ago. WPF's BitmapEffects were deemed too slow to port over, but there are Effects. Two are builtin-- BlurEffect and DropShadowEffect. Also, you can write your own pixel shaders in HLSL just like you can in WPF to achieve a broad range of effects.

Some links:
Expression Blend 3 Preview: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=A04AA0AE-87BE-4201-A65E-E792859122FC&displaylang=en

Some ShaderEffects that run in either WPF or Silverlight: http://www.codeplex.com/wpffx/

Silverlight 3 Beta: http://silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight3/default.aspx